# Select country and automatic generate phone code in Contact Form 7 plugin - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have a Contact Form 7 Plugin
I need to changes on this form check detail below 
If any related plugin please suggest me 
Select Country and auto generate phone number in text box

**Location:** India (Select in dropdown)

**Code:** +91 (automated appear)

Answer (score 9):

Add below code to the contact form 7 editor, it will display the list of countries on the form as select box

```
[select coutrylist class:allCountryList include_blank "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "AmericanSamoa" "Andorra" "Angola" "Anguilla" "Antigua and Barbuda" "Argentina" "Armenia" "Aruba" "Australia" "Austria" "Azerbaijan" "Bahamas" "Bahrain" "Bangladesh" "Barbados" "Belarus" "Belgium" "Belize" "Benin" "Bermuda" "Bhutan" "Bosnia and Herzegovina" "Botswana" "Brazil" "British Indian Ocean Territory" "Bulgaria" "Burkina Faso" "Burundi" "Cambodia" "Cameroon" "Canada" "Cape Verde" "Cayman Islands" "Central African Republic" "Chad" "Chile" "China" "Christmas Island" "Colombia" "Comoros" "Congo" "Cook Islands" "Costa Rica" "Croatia" "Cuba" "Cyprus" "Czech Republic" "Denmark" "Djibouti" "Dominica" "Dominican Republic" "Ecuador" "Egypt" "El Salvador" "Equatorial Guinea" "Eritrea" "Estonia" "Ethiopia" "Faroe Islands" "Fiji" "Finland" "France" "French Guiana" "French Polynesia" "Gabon" "Gambia" "Georgia" "Germany" "Ghana" "Gibraltar" "Greece" "Greenland" "Grenada" "Guadeloupe" "Guam" "Guatemala" "Guinea" "Guinea-Bissau" "Guyana" "Haiti" "Honduras" "Hungary" "Iceland" "India" "Indonesia" "Iraq" "Ireland" "Israel" "Italy" "Jamaica" "Japan" "Jordan" "Kazakhstan" "Kenya" "Kiribati" "Kuwait" "Kyrgyzstan" "Latvia" "Lebanon" "Lesotho" "Liberia" "Liechtenstein" "Lithuania" "Luxembourg" "Madagascar" "Malawi" "Malaysia" "Maldives" "Mali" "Malta" "Marshall Islands" "Martinique" "Mauritania" "Mauritius" "Mayotte" "Mexico" "Monaco" "Mongolia" "Montenegro" "Montserrat" "Morocco" "Myanmar" "Namibia" "Nauru" "Nepal" "Netherlands" "Netherlands Antilles" "New Caledonia" "New Zealand" "Nicaragua" "Niger" "Nigeria" "Niue" "Norfolk Island" "Northern Mariana Islands" "Norway" "Oman" "Pakistan" "Palau" "Panama" "Papua New Guinea" "Paraguay" "Peru" "Philippines" "Poland" "Portugal" "Puerto Rico" "Qatar" "Romania" "Rwanda" "Samoa" "San Marino" "Saudi Arabia" "Senegal" "Serbia" "Seychelles" "Sierra Leone" "Singapore" "Slovakia" "Slovenia" "Solomon Islands" "South Africa" "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands" "Spain" "Sri Lanka" "Sudan" "Suriname" "Swaziland" "Sweden" "Switzerland" "Tajikistan" "Thailand" "Togo" "Tokelau" "Tonga" "Trinidad and Tobago" "Tunisia" "Turkey" "Turkmenistan" "Turks and Caicos Islands" "Tuvalu" "Uganda" "Ukraine" "United Arab Emirates" "United Kingdom" "United States" "Uruguay" "Uzbekistan" "Vanuatu" "Wallis and Futuna" "Yemen" "Zambia" "Zimbabwe" "land Islands" "Antarctica" "Bolivia, Plurinational State of" "Brunei Darussalam" "Cocos (Keeling) Islands" "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the" "Cote d'Ivoire" "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)" "Guernsey" "Holy See (Vatican City State)" "Hong Kong" "Iran, Islamic Republic of" "Isle of Man" "Jersey" "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of" "Korea, Republic of" "Lao People's Democratic Republic" "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya" "Macao" "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of" "Micronesia, Federated States of" "Moldova, Republic of" "Mozambique" "Palestinian Territory, Occupied" "Pitcairn" "RÃ©union" "Russia" "Saint BarthÃ©lemy" "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan Da Cunha" "Saint Kitts and Nevis" "Saint Lucia" "Saint Martin" "Saint Pierre and Miquelon" "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" "Sao Tome and Principe" "Somalia" "Svalbard and Jan Mayen" "Syrian Arab Republic" "Taiwan, Province of China" "Tanzania, United Republic of" "Timor-Leste" "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of" "Viet Nam" "Virgin Islands, British" "Virgin Islands, U.S."]
```

Add a telephone number field with class:phoneNumber,here the country code will be displayed on selection of the country

Add the Below code to javascript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   /*On selecting country respective dialing code is updated*/

    // List of all the countries with their dialing code in json format
    var countryList = [{"name":"Afghanistan","dial_code":"+93","code":"AF"},{"name":"Albania","dial_code":"+355","code":"AL"},{"name":"Algeria","dial_code":"+213","code":"DZ"},{"name":"AmericanSamoa","dial_code":"+1 684","code":"AS"},{"name":"Andorra","dial_code":"+376","code":"AD"},{"name":"Angola","dial_code":"+244","code":"AO"},{"name":"Anguilla","dial_code":"+1 264","code":"AI"},{"name":"Antigua and Barbuda","dial_code":"+1268","code":"AG"},{"name":"Argentina","dial_code":"+54","code":"AR"},{"name":"Armenia","dial_code":"+374","code":"AM"},{"name":"Aruba","dial_code":"+297","code":"AW"},{"name":"Australia","dial_code":"+61","code":"AU"},{"name":"Austria","dial_code":"+43","code":"AT"},{"name":"Azerbaijan","dial_code":"+994","code":"AZ"},{"name":"Bahamas","dial_code":"+1 242","code":"BS"},{"name":"Bahrain","dial_code":"+973","code":"BH"},{"name":"Bangladesh","dial_code":"+880","code":"BD"},{"name":"Barbados","dial_code":"+1 246","code":"BB"},{"name":"Belarus","dial_code":"+375","code":"BY"},{"name":"Belgium","dial_code":"+32","code":"BE"},{"name":"Belize","dial_code":"+501","code":"BZ"},{"name":"Benin","dial_code":"+229","code":"BJ"},{"name":"Bermuda","dial_code":"+1 441","code":"BM"},{"name":"Bhutan","dial_code":"+975","code":"BT"},{"name":"Bosnia and Herzegovina","dial_code":"+387","code":"BA"},{"name":"Botswana","dial_code":"+267","code":"BW"},{"name":"Brazil","dial_code":"+55","code":"BR"},{"name":"British Indian Ocean Territory","dial_code":"+246","code":"IO"},{"name":"Bulgaria","dial_code":"+359","code":"BG"},{"name":"Burkina Faso","dial_code":"+226","code":"BF"},{"name":"Burundi","dial_code":"+257","code":"BI"},{"name":"Cambodia","dial_code":"+855","code":"KH"},{"name":"Cameroon","dial_code":"+237","code":"CM"},{"name":"Canada","dial_code":"+1","code":"CA"},{"name":"Cape Verde","dial_code":"+238","code":"CV"},{"name":"Cayman Islands","dial_code":"+ 345","code":"KY"},{"name":"Central African Republic","dial_code":"+236","code":"CF"},{"name":"Chad","dial_code":"+235","code":"TD"},{"name":"Chile","dial_code":"+56","code":"CL"},{"name":"China","dial_code":"+86","code":"CN"},{"name":"Christmas Island","dial_code":"+61","code":"CX"},{"name":"Colombia","dial_code":"+57","code":"CO"},{"name":"Comoros","dial_code":"+269","code":"KM"},{"name":"Congo","dial_code":"+242","code":"CG"},{"name":"Cook Islands","dial_code":"+682","code":"CK"},{"name":"Costa Rica","dial_code":"+506","code":"CR"},{"name":"Croatia","dial_code":"+385","code":"HR"},{"name":"Cuba","dial_code":"+53","code":"CU"},{"name":"Cyprus","dial_code":"+537","code":"CY"},{"name":"Czech Republic","dial_code":"+420","code":"CZ"},{"name":"Denmark","dial_code":"+45","code":"DK"},{"name":"Djibouti","dial_code":"+253","code":"DJ"},{"name":"Dominica","dial_code":"+1 767","code":"DM"},{"name":"Dominican Republic","dial_code":"+1 849","code":"DO"},{"name":"Ecuador","dial_code":"+593","code":"EC"},{"name":"Egypt","dial_code":"+20","code":"EG"},{"name":"El Salvador","dial_code":"+503","code":"SV"},{"name":"Equatorial Guinea","dial_code":"+240","code":"GQ"},{"name":"Eritrea","dial_code":"+291","code":"ER"},{"name":"Estonia","dial_code":"+372","code":"EE"},{"name":"Ethiopia","dial_code":"+251","code":"ET"},{"name":"Faroe Islands","dial_code":"+298","code":"FO"},{"name":"Fiji","dial_code":"+679","code":"FJ"},{"name":"Finland","dial_code":"+358","code":"FI"},{"name":"France","dial_code":"+33","code":"FR"},{"name":"French Guiana","dial_code":"+594","code":"GF"},{"name":"French Polynesia","dial_code":"+689","code":"PF"},{"name":"Gabon","dial_code":"+241","code":"GA"},{"name":"Gambia","dial_code":"+220","code":"GM"},{"name":"Georgia","dial_code":"+995","code":"GE"},{"name":"Germany","dial_code":"+49","code":"DE"},{"name":"Ghana","dial_code":"+233","code":"GH"},{"name":"Gibraltar","dial_code":"+350","code":"GI"},{"name":"Greece","dial_code":"+30","code":"GR"},{"name":"Greenland","dial_code":"+299","code":"GL"},{"name":"Grenada","dial_code":"+1 473","code":"GD"},{"name":"Guadeloupe","dial_code":"+590","code":"GP"},{"name":"Guam","dial_code":"+1 671","code":"GU"},{"name":"Guatemala","dial_code":"+502","code":"GT"},{"name":"Guinea","dial_code":"+224","code":"GN"},{"name":"Guinea-Bissau","dial_code":"+245","code":"GW"},{"name":"Guyana","dial_code":"+595","code":"GY"},{"name":"Haiti","dial_code":"+509","code":"HT"},{"name":"Honduras","dial_code":"+504","code":"HN"},{"name":"Hungary","dial_code":"+36","code":"HU"},{"name":"Iceland","dial_code":"+354","code":"IS"},{"name":"India","dial_code":"+91","code":"IN"},{"name":"Indonesia","dial_code":"+62","code":"ID"},{"name":"Iraq","dial_code":"+964","code":"IQ"},{"name":"Ireland","dial_code":"+353","code":"IE"},{"name":"Israel","dial_code":"+972","code":"IL"},{"name":"Italy","dial_code":"+39","code":"IT"},{"name":"Jamaica","dial_code":"+1 876","code":"JM"},{"name":"Japan","dial_code":"+81","code":"JP"},{"name":"Jordan","dial_code":"+962","code":"JO"},{"name":"Kazakhstan","dial_code":"+7 7","code":"KZ"},{"name":"Kenya","dial_code":"+254","code":"KE"},{"name":"Kiribati","dial_code":"+686","code":"KI"},{"name":"Kuwait","dial_code":"+965","code":"KW"},{"name":"Kyrgyzstan","dial_code":"+996","code":"KG"},{"name":"Latvia","dial_code":"+371","code":"LV"},{"name":"Lebanon","dial_code":"+961","code":"LB"},{"name":"Lesotho","dial_code":"+266","code":"LS"},{"name":"Liberia","dial_code":"+231","code":"LR"},{"name":"Liechtenstein","dial_code":"+423","code":"LI"},{"name":"Lithuania","dial_code":"+370","code":"LT"},{"name":"Luxembourg","dial_code":"+352","code":"LU"},{"name":"Madagascar","dial_code":"+261","code":"MG"},{"name":"Malawi","dial_code":"+265","code":"MW"},{"name":"Malaysia","dial_code":"+60","code":"MY"},{"name":"Maldives","dial_code":"+960","code":"MV"},{"name":"Mali","dial_code":"+223","code":"ML"},{"name":"Malta","dial_code":"+356","code":"MT"},{"name":"Marshall Islands","dial_code":"+692","code":"MH"},{"name":"Martinique","dial_code":"+596","code":"MQ"},{"name":"Mauritania","dial_code":"+222","code":"MR"},{"name":"Mauritius","dial_code":"+230","code":"MU"},{"name":"Mayotte","dial_code":"+262","code":"YT"},{"name":"Mexico","dial_code":"+52","code":"MX"},{"name":"Monaco","dial_code":"+377","code":"MC"},{"name":"Mongolia","dial_code":"+976","code":"MN"},{"name":"Montenegro","dial_code":"+382","code":"ME"},{"name":"Montserrat","dial_code":"+1664","code":"MS"},{"name":"Morocco","dial_code":"+212","code":"MA"},{"name":"Myanmar","dial_code":"+95","code":"MM"},{"name":"Namibia","dial_code":"+264","code":"NA"},{"name":"Nauru","dial_code":"+674","code":"NR"},{"name":"Nepal","dial_code":"+977","code":"NP"},{"name":"Netherlands","dial_code":"+31","code":"NL"},{"name":"Netherlands Antilles","dial_code":"+599","code":"AN"},{"name":"New Caledonia","dial_code":"+687","code":"NC"},{"name":"New Zealand","dial_code":"+64","code":"NZ"},{"name":"Nicaragua","dial_code":"+505","code":"NI"},{"name":"Niger","dial_code":"+227","code":"NE"},{"name":"Nigeria","dial_code":"+234","code":"NG"},{"name":"Niue","dial_code":"+683","code":"NU"},{"name":"Norfolk Island","dial_code":"+672","code":"NF"},{"name":"Northern Mariana Islands","dial_code":"+1 670","code":"MP"},{"name":"Norway","dial_code":"+47","code":"NO"},{"name":"Oman","dial_code":"+968","code":"OM"},{"name":"Pakistan","dial_code":"+92","code":"PK"},{"name":"Palau","dial_code":"+680","code":"PW"},{"name":"Panama","dial_code":"+507","code":"PA"},{"name":"Papua New Guinea","dial_code":"+675","code":"PG"},{"name":"Paraguay","dial_code":"+595","code":"PY"},{"name":"Peru","dial_code":"+51","code":"PE"},{"name":"Philippines","dial_code":"+63","code":"PH"},{"name":"Poland","dial_code":"+48","code":"PL"},{"name":"Portugal","dial_code":"+351","code":"PT"},{"name":"Puerto Rico","dial_code":"+1 939","code":"PR"},{"name":"Qatar","dial_code":"+974","code":"QA"},{"name":"Romania","dial_code":"+40","code":"RO"},{"name":"Rwanda","dial_code":"+250","code":"RW"},{"name":"Samoa","dial_code":"+685","code":"WS"},{"name":"San Marino","dial_code":"+378","code":"SM"},{"name":"Saudi Arabia","dial_code":"+966","code":"SA"},{"name":"Senegal","dial_code":"+221","code":"SN"},{"name":"Serbia","dial_code":"+381","code":"RS"},{"name":"Seychelles","dial_code":"+248","code":"SC"},{"name":"Sierra Leone","dial_code":"+232","code":"SL"},{"name":"Singapore","dial_code":"+65","code":"SG"},{"name":"Slovakia","dial_code":"+421","code":"SK"},{"name":"Slovenia","dial_code":"+386","code":"SI"},{"name":"Solomon Islands","dial_code":"+677","code":"SB"},{"name":"South Africa","dial_code":"+27","code":"ZA"},{"name":"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands","dial_code":"+500","code":"GS"},{"name":"Spain","dial_code":"+34","code":"ES"},{"name":"Sri Lanka","dial_code":"+94","code":"LK"},{"name":"Sudan","dial_code":"+249","code":"SD"},{"name":"Suriname","dial_code":"+597","code":"SR"},{"name":"Swaziland","dial_code":"+268","code":"SZ"},{"name":"Sweden","dial_code":"+46","code":"SE"},{"name":"Switzerland","dial_code":"+41","code":"CH"},{"name":"Tajikistan","dial_code":"+992","code":"TJ"},{"name":"Thailand","dial_code":"+66","code":"TH"},{"name":"Togo","dial_code":"+228","code":"TG"},{"name":"Tokelau","dial_code":"+690","code":"TK"},{"name":"Tonga","dial_code":"+676","code":"TO"},{"name":"Trinidad and Tobago","dial_code":"+1 868","code":"TT"},{"name":"Tunisia","dial_code":"+216","code":"TN"},{"name":"Turkey","dial_code":"+90","code":"TR"},{"name":"Turkmenistan","dial_code":"+993","code":"TM"},{"name":"Turks and Caicos Islands","dial_code":"+1 649","code":"TC"},{"name":"Tuvalu","dial_code":"+688","code":"TV"},{"name":"Uganda","dial_code":"+256","code":"UG"},{"name":"Ukraine","dial_code":"+380","code":"UA"},{"name":"United Arab Emirates","dial_code":"+971","code":"AE"},{"name":"United Kingdom","dial_code":"+44","code":"GB"},{"name":"United States","dial_code":"+1","code":"US"},{"name":"Uruguay","dial_code":"+598","code":"UY"},{"name":"Uzbekistan","dial_code":"+998","code":"UZ"},{"name":"Vanuatu","dial_code":"+678","code":"VU"},{"name":"Wallis and Futuna","dial_code":"+681","code":"WF"},{"name":"Yemen","dial_code":"+967","code":"YE"},{"name":"Zambia","dial_code":"+260","code":"ZM"},{"name":"Zimbabwe","dial_code":"+263","code":"ZW"},{"name":"land Islands","dial_code":"","code":"AX"},{"name":"Antarctica","dial_code":null,"code":"AQ"},{"name":"Bolivia, Plurinational State of","dial_code":"+591","code":"BO"},{"name":"Brunei Darussalam","dial_code":"+673","code":"BN"},{"name":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands","dial_code":"+61","code":"CC"},{"name":"Congo, The Democratic Republic of the","dial_code":"+243","code":"CD"},{"name":"Cote d'Ivoire","dial_code":"+225","code":"CI"},{"name":"Falkland Islands (Malvinas)","dial_code":"+500","code":"FK"},{"name":"Guernsey","dial_code":"+44","code":"GG"},{"name":"Holy See (Vatican City State)","dial_code":"+379","code":"VA"},{"name":"Hong Kong","dial_code":"+852","code":"HK"},{"name":"Iran, Islamic Republic of","dial_code":"+98","code":"IR"},{"name":"Isle of Man","dial_code":"+44","code":"IM"},{"name":"Jersey","dial_code":"+44","code":"JE"},{"name":"Korea, Democratic People's Republic of","dial_code":"+850","code":"KP"},{"name":"Korea, Republic of","dial_code":"+82","code":"KR"},{"name":"Lao People's Democratic Republic","dial_code":"+856","code":"LA"},{"name":"Libyan Arab Jamahiriya","dial_code":"+218","code":"LY"},{"name":"Macao","dial_code":"+853","code":"MO"},{"name":"Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of","dial_code":"+389","code":"MK"},{"name":"Micronesia, Federated States of","dial_code":"+691","code":"FM"},{"name":"Moldova, Republic of","dial_code":"+373","code":"MD"},{"name":"Mozambique","dial_code":"+258","code":"MZ"},{"name":"Palestinian Territory, Occupied","dial_code":"+970","code":"PS"},{"name":"Pitcairn","dial_code":"+872","code":"PN"},{"name":"Réunion","dial_code":"+262","code":"RE"},{"name":"Russia","dial_code":"+7","code":"RU"},{"name":"Saint Barthélemy","dial_code":"+590","code":"BL"},{"name":"Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan Da Cunha","dial_code":"+290","code":"SH"},{"name":"Saint Kitts and Nevis","dial_code":"+1 869","code":"KN"},{"name":"Saint Lucia","dial_code":"+1 758","code":"LC"},{"name":"Saint Martin","dial_code":"+590","code":"MF"},{"name":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon","dial_code":"+508","code":"PM"},{"name":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","dial_code":"+1 784","code":"VC"},{"name":"Sao Tome and Principe","dial_code":"+239","code":"ST"},{"name":"Somalia","dial_code":"+252","code":"SO"},{"name":"Svalbard and Jan Mayen","dial_code":"+47","code":"SJ"},{"name":"Syrian Arab Republic","dial_code":"+963","code":"SY"},{"name":"Taiwan, Province of China","dial_code":"+886","code":"TW"},{"name":"Tanzania, United Republic of","dial_code":"+255","code":"TZ"},{"name":"Timor-Leste","dial_code":"+670","code":"TL"},{"name":"Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of","dial_code":"+58","code":"VE"},{"name":"Viet Nam","dial_code":"+84","code":"VN"},{"name":"Virgin Islands, British","dial_code":"+1 284","code":"VG"},{"name":"Virgin Islands, U.S.","dial_code":"+1 340","code":"VI"}];

    jQuery('.allCountryList').change(function() {
        selectedCountry = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery.each(countryList,function(idx, obj) {
            if(selectedCountry == obj.name){
                CountryNumberCode = obj.dial_code;
                jQuery('.phoneNumber').val(CountryNumberCode);
            }
        });
    });

});
```